# og:description not showing up in Facebook feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm trying to implement a basic Facebook like functionality to a site. I've triple-checked & more the meta tags, but the og:description -text doesn't show up in the FB news feed. The title and the image work fine.

Here's the code:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="SOG – VEITSIÄ VIIDAKOSTA ARKITÖIHIN" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.finnprotec.fi/webshop/news/2" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Kunhan kirjoitan vaan jotain tekstia nyt." />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Finnprotec.fi" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.finnprotec.fi/webshop/kuvat/kuva517a8539a91f1.jpg" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="6700009220" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="348235131938688" />
```

When I click on the link on the page, the description shows up nicely under the title:

[image: When I click on the link on the page:]

But when I click on the send button, this shows up on my FB feed:

[image: But when I click on the send button, this shows up on my FB feed:]

This is what I'm trying to get:

[image: This is what I'm trying to get:]

The url of the current page is: http://www.finnprotec.fi/webshop/news/2

I have tried to clear facebook's cache with the facebook linter, but that hasn't helped.

Comment: Well, no and yes. Different FB APIs rendered different results, the best and most reliable one was the method using the sharer.php. Using the Like/Recommend -button was the most unreliable way, it rendered different layouts based on the image dimensions and whatnot. So I ended up using the sharer.php for shares and the default Like-button (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) for likes.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this.  I found that the description is actually there - you have to hover over the image to see it.  It shows it in the format you want sometimes, depending on the size of the post where you're viewing it.

For example, after I've liked my post, I don't see the description in the post shown when I click on my name and view my wall (where the posts are smaller).

But I do see it when I just go to facebook.com and I view the larger version shown in my stream.

I realize this isn't really answering the question; I couldn't find a way to get it to show the description consistently.

Comment: There is a standard wall post and a featured wall post now, perhaps you only get the description if Facebook's algorithm decides to feature your shared post. I've spent a lot of time trying to get meta data and sharing buttons perfect and sometimes they still don't work 100% correctly for every single person that clicks them. There is also a time delay, sometimes if you go for coffee and come back and look the meta data has magically appeared correctly only later on.

Answer (score -5):

add this two lines to your code after og:image

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

it must work